# tSQLt unit test hanging and giving a 'A severe error happened during test execution. Test did not finish.' error?

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

When I run a unit test in tSQLt, the procedure just hangs in executing state. The unit test only contains a single stored procedure. 
When I run the stored procedure directly, it executes successfully.

> A severe error happened during test execution. Test did not finish

My tSQLt framework is in a different database than where my stored procedure lives. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

```
USE [tSQLt_Example]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [SimsTests].[test medata bill review import process] 
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sims.bhhc.Interface_Insert_BillReviewPayment @BillReviewSettingID = 12         

    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 0, 0
END
```

Comment: will it work if you do BEGIN TRANSACTION EXEC sims... ROLLBACK?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I could try it but tSQLt supposedly runs their unit tests inside a transaction already.

Comment: I know, that's why I ask you to test that your SP will not fail if you wrap it into transaction.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I wrapped the SP in BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK and got the same issue. So there must be something in the SP causing it to hang on a rollback.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever got to the bottom of this issue but you do need to have the tSQLt framework installed in the same database as the one you are writing your tests.

The idea with tSQLt is that you should not be writing your tests against a production database but rather an empty copy of you database.  You can can populate lookup tables (static data) but other than that you should not have data in the database. You would then set up your data as part of a test. As you know the test runs in a transaction so at the end of your test all the data needed for that test will be rolled back and you will be left with the database as it was prior to your test.  tSQLt has a number of powerful features that allow you to test by only populating with the data you need (have a look at Fake tables).

If you haven't used tSQLt before it takes a bit of time to get your head around the mechanics, but once you've got it, you will find it's very easy to work with and you will gain a lot of confidence in your SQL code that has test coverage.